# Подгрузка данных на страницу без перезагрузки

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

На странице есть html структура(таблица):

```
<div class="book__table">
                            <div class="book__table-row">
                                <div style="width: 10%" class="book__table-progress book__table-progress--green"></div>
                                <div class="book__table-item">1.17<span>452</span></div>
                                <div class="book__table-item">0.102<span>4244</span></div>
                                <div class="book__table-item book__table-item--green">0.18<span>4</span></div>
                            </div>
```

В БД есть таблица с постоянно появляющимися записями, вот пример одной: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как сделать так, чтобы при появлении новых записей в БД, они автоматически заносились в мою структуру html на странице? Нужно заносить только 3 поля: price, amount, total. Знаю что делается с помощью jquery и функции append, но разобраться до конца не могу.

Answer (score 0):

Простой пример на ajax

```
function script(){
    $.ajax({
        url: 'script.php',
        success: function(data) {
            // в script.php возвращайте json или массив и подставляйте здесь значение (data.price и т.д.)
            $('.book__table').append("<div class='book__table-row'><div style='width: 10%' class='book__table-progress book__table-progress--green'></div><div class='book__table-item'>1.17<span>452</span></div><div class='book__table-item'>0.102<span>4244</span></div><div class='book__table-item book__table-item--green'>0.18<span>4</span></div></div>");
        }
    });
}

setInterval(script(), 10000); // проверяем каждые 10 секунд
```

Comment: каждые 10 секунд != при появлении новых записей в БД

Comment: @Diskyp, 10 секунд это пример, нужно только чтобы php отдавал новые добавленные записи, более профессионально это конечно использовать websocket и при постоянном соединении следить за таблицей

Comment: да, именно, для решения конкретно этой задачи нужны сокеты, самодудос аяксом здесь будет неуместен